# Getting wrong character encoding when selecting with PostgreSQL in Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, utf-8, ascii, charset

I'm trying to get some data from PostgreSQL using Node.js, but when I use `SELECT * FROM table` it returns me wrong characters, but in console it didn't happen.

Only ASCII characters are shown, but not UTF-8 characters. My entire database is encoded using UTF-8, and I'm trying to change the charset in Node.js.

I tried this:

```js
await pgClient.query(`SET client_encoding = 'utf-8'`);
```

But didn't work.

This is an example of what is returning in bash:

```sql
SELECT * FROM example; -- This returns "María"
```

But this is the response with Node.js:

```js
await pgClient.query('SELECT * FROM example'); // This returns me "Mar¢a"
```

Comment: How do you run SQL "from bash"? And how do you print/inspect the result of the query ran from node.js?

Comment: I'm writing a Discord Bot, and the result is the same in a Discord message and using `console.log()`.

"from bash" refers that I'm using raw PostgreSQL with cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was just a Windows moment. The Windows Console works with a WINXXXX encoding, while PostgreSQL in Node.js works with UTF8 by default.

The solution is simple, just change your `client_encoding` to `UTF8` or `LATIN1` while using the terminal:

```sql
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
```